# Eigenvetor Property of a Matrix

Tags: matrix-analysis

If a matrix $A$ is complex orthogonally similar to an upper triangular matrix, that is, $A=QUQ^T, Q^TQ=I$ and $U$ is upper triangular matrix,  then there exist at least one eigenvector $x$ of $A$ such that $x^Tx\neq 0.$

This is an exercise in Horn and Johnson. Don't know how to start. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: First step: assume $A$ is upper triangular. Is it easier to prove there? How might your proof change if we throw in the $Q$s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: exhibit an eigenvector $y(\neq 0)$ of $U$, and note that $x=Qy$ is then an eigenvector of $A$.